# No file attachment object available in InfoPath?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I can't locate the attachment file control in InfoPath? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Make sure that the lists attachment setting is enabled from the lists advanced settings in SharePoint.

Comment: Reposted the answer as answer to the question so you can mark it and close the thread. :)

Comment: How do I close the thread?...

Comment: Below the voting system on the left of my answer, there should be a checkmark. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the lists attachment setting is enabled from the lists advanced settings in SharePoint.

Enable it and then refresh the form in InfoPath, otherwise you will need to close the form and reopen it, and then the attachment control should be available from the field section to the right.